# Pular Activities de cadastro de usuário já logado no aplicativo

Tags: android, login, android-activity

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de pular `Activities` de cadastro ao inicializar a aplicação no Android quando o usuário já está cadastrado no aplicativo, como ocorre no Facebook e outros aplicativos que necessitam de login.

O jeito ideal seria consultar no banco `SQLite` se o usuário já é existente e criar uma `Intent` na criação dessa primeira Activity e redicionar logo para outra `Activity`? Ou qual outra maneira utilizariam? Existe uma maneira de acessar o aplicativo sem criar a `Activity` que é iniciada a aplicação pela primeira vez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua Activity inicial pode ser assim (note que não há `setContentView()`):

```
public class ActivityInicial extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (usuarioLogado()) {
            chamarActivityPrincipal();
        } else {
            chamarActivityDeLogin();
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```